# How do I get Marble's bonus to Wonder construction?

Tags: civilization-5

Hovering over the Marble resource icon indicates "+15% Production when building Ancient and Classical Era Wonders in the City where it is worked". What does it mean "to work" in this case? Just having a Citizen on it? Do I need Masonry?

Comment: This is one of those easy questions that, while allowed, is not going to be well received, as it shows a dramatic lack of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a Quarry on Marble (which requires the Masonry technology) to reap its rewards. I don't think there's any other way. Great Tile Improvements do not connect Luxury Resources to the empire's trade network.

Comment: It's only a quarry - this is really easily found online.